# Using a variable from a different subprogram

Tags: python, variables

I need to create program code in python that uses a defined variable from a different subprogram using a simple version:

```
x = 'ham'

def a():
    x = 'cheese'

def b():
    print(x)
a()
b()
```

How do I get this to save the global variable x as cheese instead of ham?

Comment: OT @Claudiu: Salut. Vezi ca [website link-ul din profilul tau](http://stackoverflow.com/users/15055/claudiu) e broken.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you mutate a global variable in a function, you have to explicitly declare that you're using it as a global:

```
x = 1

def a():
    global x
    x = 4

def b():
    print(x)

a()
b()
```

Otherwise, `a` just creates a local variable `x` that shadows the global.

Comment: Nah. The question is asking how to reference a variable defined in another subprogram/function. `x` is globally defined in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing by subprogram you mean function?

The reason you are getting a 1 instead of a 4 is because `x = 1` sets a *global* variable (in the *global* scope).

When you do `x = 4` inside of a function it creates a *local* variable (in that function's *local* scope).  Once the function is finished, the local variables are discarded.

When you call `b()` and it tries to look up the value of x, there is no *local* variable x (in b's local scope) so it uses the *global* variable x, which is 1.

If you want `a()` to modify the *global* variable x, you have to options:

1) You can just modify the global variable explicitly

```
def a():
    global x
    x = 4
```

2) You can return the local varaible and assign it to the global (preferred)

```
def a():
    x = 4
    return x

x = a()
```